# ListView row height with ImageView

Tags: android, listview, layout, imageview

I have a Listview with a custom rows which contains:

```
Button  TextView         ImageView ImageView  Button

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bonus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/green_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:text="Test" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bonus"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/images_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/missed"
    android:background="#ffff0000"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/live"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/missed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/red_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
         android:text="test2" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

So here on a small screen for example (Wildfire) the two button and the text look good but my Image being a size 72x72 will stretches the row height and I will have a very tall and it doesn't look nice..

How can I resize automatically the image to fit the row and to be the same size as the buttons ?

Thank you! (I can attach an image if this is not clear)

Comment: Add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your `ImageView`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html for more scaling options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the ImageView to be the same height as the button, make it align top and bottom to the button. This will guarantee the height match.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id"@+id/images_layout"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/bonus"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/bonus"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name" >

...
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/images_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/missed"
    android:background="#ffff0000"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/name"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/live"

            />

</LinearLayout>
```